# Mirror Multiple object or parent and sub meshes

Tags: modeling

Might be a funny question, but how can I mirror multiple objects? I made one side of the headphone with multiple meshes and parent them together. Is there a way I can mirror then easily? Or the only way is to mirror then to an Empty axis object one by one?

Doing ctrl+J messes with the modifiers of each object.

Comment: Kinda depends what you wish to do.  If for example it was a simple axle with a wheel on each end.  You might want to mirror half the axis, but have the wheels as separate objects, aligned as if mirrored, but having the ability to transform independantly.

Answer (score 1):

You can transfer Modifier or "Link" them from one object to others.

By selecting multiple objects and pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> you get a menu that looks somewhat like this:

[image]

By clicking on modifiers, the modifiers of the last selected Object (your active Object) get copied over to the other selected objects. That way you can Setup one Object the way you want and just transfer the modifier to the other objects.

Comment: Worth noting that this wipes out any other modifiers that already exist in the other objects in the process, so this needs to happen before additional modifiers are created.